# Use API with sdk higher than my Minimum SDK

Tags: android, api, paypal, sdk

I want to implement the Paypal API in the next update of my app. When adding the dependencies, it says that my min SDK (15) is to low to get the api which requires 16.

I know I could just bump my min SDK to 16 and solve it but I don't want to drop the devices running my app on API 15. The update covers other things than just Paypal so I want all my users to benefit from it and the elligible ones to get the Paypal implementation. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Neo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741586/neo)'s answer I've found this solution.

I can override the min SDK for a certain Library and handle in myself in the code with this line in the app manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="YOUR_MIN_SDK" tools:overrideLibrary="the.library.to.override"/>
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= 16){
          // Call your function that will run the updated paypal implementation
    } else{
         // Run your old implementation of paypal
    }
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: The thing is that I don't have an old one and that I need to compile with the right dependencies, thing I can't do right now because of my min SDK

Comment: For this you need to make decision, because even you skip paypal part for sdk less than 16 then all app will work without payment. Better to check their repositry, their must be older implementation that should support < 16 api version.

Comment: Some do, but for security purpose, I prefer using the newest one with the latest security features and improvements

Comment: Correct. But you can't use newer APIs with older os version :)

Comment: Hence, the reason for my answer ;) I don,t have much people using my app with api 15 and if they are, they can still use most options except payment and pay on the web instead